# How do you upload folders to one drive?

Tags: onedrive

I am a Google Drive user right now, but I want to switch over to onedrive. I converted all my files (about 100 or so) to .docx format or .pdf, but when i try uploading, it doesnt allow me to upload folder! How can I do this without wasting hours of my time? I have a mac and windows. I downloaded the software from microsoft for syncing.

Comment: Just place them in your `Onedrive` folder.  It happens automatically.

Comment: Ah, how stupid of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to install OneDrive for desktop and then drag the folder you want to upload, into the OneDrive Sync Folder.

Answer (score 2):

**Sorry, OneDrive can't upload folders or empty files**
To upload files to a new folder in OneDrive, first create the folder, and then upload the files to it. Files that are 0 bytes in size can't be uploaded from the OneDrive website.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/upload-file-cant-faq